# Symfony2 Validate registration Form - Email (two validators)

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I have a simple registration form with an address-entity.

I do validate the value of each property using the `loadValidatorMetadata(...) {...}` method.

I want to check if the email is valide (by characters, etc...) and if email1 is equal to email2 and email1 hasn't to be in the bad-index-array.

Setting the validation is easy. But how can I define different errors-messages for each case?

code example:

```
public $email;

public $email2;

static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
{
    ...

    $metadata->addGetterConstraint('email', new Assert\False(array(
        'message' => 'validation.addressFormEmail'
    )));

    ...
}

public function getEmail()
{
    if ($this->email == $this->email2) {
            return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Where do you validate your values ? Do you have one validator for each rule ?

Answer (score 0):

Symfony2 has a repeated form type where you can set your message if the value isn't repeated.
then in your entity validation you can set a custom message for email validation.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html#validation
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Email.html

Comment: Sorry, i forgotten... i dont use the formbuilder. And i dont use doctrine.

Comment: you don't need doctrine to use validation annotations.  So you can use that and then just check that they are equal to each to each other when you receive the form data and then add the error yourself.